# Append 2 rows from 1 row with unique data in each

Tags: sql, ms-access

Very new to Access, thanks for your patience:

I have 2 tables which are records of bridge supports. The supports are numbered. In one of these tables there is one row of information for each support #, lets call it tblSupport. In the other table I would like to have 2 rows corresponding to each support #, each row corresponding to one side of the bridge or the other (e.g. left, right)--lets call the table tblPosts.

I have a form that allows a user to input a record for a new support in tblSupport, including the identifying # for that support. I currently have it so once the info is entered and a "save" button is clicked, it adds the record for that support to the table and appends a row to tblPosts with the same support # so that another user can enter data regarding the posts for that support.

Each time a user enters data for a new support in tblSupport (via a form) and clicks "save" I would like to append 2 rows to tblPosts, both with the same support #, but in another field called 'Side' I would like one row to show 'Left', and the other to show 'Right'. So then tblPosts would be ready for the next user to enter data for both the Left and Right posts for a single Support.

Any tips on how to do this? Please let me know if I need to clarify anything

Answer (score 0):

That would be two sql INSERT actions. But have to make sure the parent record is saved first. Assuming SuppID is text type field, something like:
`If Me.NewRecord Then
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblPosts(SuppID, Side) VALUES('" & Me.SuppID & "', 'Left')
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblPosts(SuppID, Side) Values('" & Me.SuppID & "', 'Right')
End If`
The real trick is figuring out what event to put this code into. Maybe SuppID textbox AfterUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach here could be improved.  If your form inserts a row into the row table when the user saves the support record you're generating a row in second table that consist of only a foreign key and no substantive data.  A better way to handle this is to only generate rows in the post table when the user needs to actually record data about posts.  Then you won't have any rows sitting around with no data.

So first, change your existing save button to only add a record to `tblSupport`.  Then you would create a second form for entering data for `tblPosts`, and either embed it into your existing form as a [subform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b) or add a button like "Add Post Record" to your existing form that opens the second form.  I'd use a subform.

The key to making the subform work is to set the Master/Child link fields.  You'll find that in the "Data" section of the subform properties, which looks like this:

[image]

You would use your "support #" ID field where my example has "HRS_Pkey".  This sets the relationship between the two fields, using the "support #" value to link the records in the two tables.  When the user enters data into the subform it will be added to the child table with the appropriate "support #" value.  You can design the subform any way you like; I tend to use datasheet subforms, but since you always want 2 child records for each parent record you'd likely want something more static.

Comment: The purpose of generating a "blank" row in tblPosts is so that the user entering data in that table knows that data has been entered in tblSupport and therefore is ready for them to enter post information. The processes are sequential: user entering "posts" information is dependent on the "supports" person having done their job and made a record of it before the posts person can do likewise. There is a separate form for entering posts data. And the "supports" person, for example, should never have reason to enter "posts" data and vice versa. would you still recommend your approach?

Comment: Basically, yes. If the supports user doesn't do anything with posts, then keep their form simple, just adding the record to `tblSupport`. For the "posts" user you'd have something like I describe above, but without adding new records. They'd select a "supports" record that already exists and add "posts" data to a subform. So the form design changes to match your workflow, but the data structure/method is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Due to inexperience with subforms I've chosen to go the route suggested by June7. To clarify here, the 'supports' and 'posts' I've been referring to for demonstration's sake are actually called 'bents' and 'micropiles.'

Ultimately I wanted it to be the case that when the bent person clicks "Save Changes" on 'Bent log form', the list of bents on 'Micropile log' is updated to reflect the same--but I do not want to append duplicate records--the LEFT JOIN ... WHERE.. IS NULL statement takes care of that. And for every new record entered, I wanted 2 rows added to the Micropile log with the same Bent #, but with a row each saying 'River' and 'Mountain' in the 'River/Mt side' column.

It's messy but it seems to work:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Micropile log]" & _
        "SELECT [Bent log].[Bent #]" & _
        "FROM [Bent log] LEFT JOIN [Micropile log] ON [Micropile log].[Bent #] = [Bent log].[Bent #]" & _
        "WHERE [Micropile log].[Bent #] IS NULL;" 'Appends added bents to Micropile Log table
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Micropile log]" & _
        "SET [River/Mt side] = 'River'" & _
        "WHERE [Bent #] = [Forms]![Bent log form]![BentNumber]" & _
        "AND [River/Mt side] IS NULL;"
        If howManyBents < 2 Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Micropile log]([Bent #], [River/Mt side])" & _
           "VALUES([Forms]![Bent log form]![BentNumber], 'Mountain');"
        End If
```

variable 'howManyBents' is a DCount function that counts the number of instances that the value in the text box for the record being entered appears in [Micropile log].[Bent #]

Any further suggestions are always appreciated. Thanks to both @Rominus and @June7 for prompt and concise responses to the original question.